# Java Application Server Performance

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I've got a somewhat dated Java EE application running on Sun Application Server 8.1 (aka SJSAS, precursor to Glassfish).  With 500+ simultaneous users the application becomes unacceptably slow and I'm trying to assist in identifying where most of the execution time is spent and what can be done to speed it up.  So far, we've been experimenting and measuring with LoadRunner, the app server logs, Oracle statpack, snoop, adjusting the app server acceptor and session (worker) threads, adjusting Hibernate batch size and join fetch use, etc but after some initial gains we're struggling to improve matters more.

Ok, with that introduction to the problem, here's the real question: If you had a slow Java EE application running on a box whose CPU and memory use never went above 20% and while running with 500+ users you showed two things: 1) that requesting even static files within the same app server JVM process was exceedingly slow, and 2) that requesting a static file outside of the app server JVM process but on the same box was fast, what would you investigate?

My thoughts initially jumped to the application server threads, both acceptor and session threads, thinking that even requests for static files were being queued, waiting for an available thread, and if the CPU/memory weren't really taxed then more threads were in order.  But then we upped both the acceptor and session threads substantially and there was no improvement.

Clarification Edits:

1) Static files should be served by a web server rather than an app server.  I am using the fact that in our case this (unfortunately) is not the configuration so that I can see the app server performance for files that it doesn't execute -- therefore excluding any database performance costs, etc.

2) I don't think there is a proxy between the requesters and the app server but even if there was it doesn't seem to be overloaded because static files requested from the same application server machine but outside of the application's JVM instance return immediately.

3) The JVM heap size (Xmx) is set to 1GB.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are the requests proxied (via Apache, etc.) before they arrive to the SJSAS?

Comment: To my knowledge, requests are not proxied.  Requests are going directly from the LoadRunner machines to the application server process.  But that is a very good suggestion to confirm so that I have no doubt.  I'll post an update when I've confirmed.  Thanks!.

Comment: Have you taken a look at JVM heap size?

Comment: digitalsanctum and matt b, I've responded to your questions in the Clarification Edits section of the original question.  Thanks!

Comment: does you app uses EJBs? check the pool/cache sizes, increase if necessary

Comment: There are no EJBs in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using a Sun performance monitoring tool we found that the garbage collector was running every couple seconds and that only about 100MB out of the 1GB heap was being used.  So we tried adding the following JVM options and, so far, this new configuration as **greatly** improved performance.

-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AggressiveHeap

See http://java.sun.com/docs/performance/appserver/AppServerPerfFaq.html

Our lesson: don't leave JVM option tuning and garbage collection adjustments to the end.  If you're having performance trouble, look at these settings early in your troubleshooting process.

Comment: GC running once in 2 seconds on almost empty heap affects the performance? O_O how "greatly" was it, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

SunONE itself is a pain in the ass. I have a very same problem, and you know what? A simple redeploy of the same application to Weblogic reduced the memory consumption and CPU consumption by about 30%.

SunONE is a reference implementation server, and shouldn't be used for production (don't know about Glassfish).

I know, this answer doesn't really helps, but I've noticed considerable pauses even in a very simple operations, such as getting a bean instance from a pool.

May be, trying to deploy JBoss or Weblogic on the same machine would give you a hint?

P.S. You shouldn't serve static content from under application server (though I do it too sometimes, when CPU is abundant).

P.P.S. 500 concurrent users is quite high a load, I'd definetely put SunONE behind a caching proxy or Apache which serves static content.